# How can I read this stem-leaf plot correctly?

Tags: statistics, spss, stem

[image: myplot]

Like the title, I used online an online data set for stem-leaf plot. But I don't know how to read it. For example, in the line of `Stem 7.` and `Leaf .5555`, why `Frequency = 18`? And what does the line `Each leaf: 4 case(s)` mean?
Every answer is very helpful to me.

Comment: Don't hide questions in the title. Show your [mcve] so people have context for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
DATA LIST FREE /x1.
BEGIN DATA.
10 22 22 13 14 10 16 17 17 17
END DATA.

EXAMINE VARIABLES=x1 /PLOT STEMLEAF.

x1 Stem-and-Leaf Plot

 Frequency    Stem &  Leaf

     4.00        1 .  0034
     4.00        1 .  6777
     2.00        2 .  22

 Stem width:     10.00
 Each leaf:        1 case(s)
```

In these data, the "Stem" is the tens place of each value and the "Leaf" is the ones place. There are four cases in the first line, representing the values 10, 10, 13, and 14 in the data. That's why "Frequency" is 4; there are four cases. There are only 2 in the last one, for both values of 22 in the original data. As the data get larger, StemLeaf plots can get a little harder to read, but the other real value of them is their shape, which gives you an idea of the shape of the distribution. For another view of that shape, ask SPSS to produce a histogram.